# How to make an AJAX call wait for a server side response?

Tags: ajax, jquery

These are my files :

**index.html**

```
<form action="#" method="POST">                           
<label for="Username">Username :</label><br/>  <input type="text" id="Username" name="username"/><span id="usr"></span><br/>  
<label for="Email">Email :</label><br/>  <input type="text" id="Email" name="email"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Register" id="submit"/>
</form>
```

**userresponse.php**

```
<?php
require ("DBC.php");
$usern = $_POST["username"];
function isAvailable($str)
        {
            $sql= "SELECT username FROM mytable WHERE username = '$str'";
            $result=mysql_query($sql)or die();
            $count = mysql_num_rows($result);

            if($count>0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
         }

if (isAvailable($usern) == true)
     echo "false";
else    
     echo "true";

?>
```

**checkuser.js**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
var usrn = $("#Username");
var usr  = $("#usr");

usrn.blur(function(){
if(usrn.val()=="")
    {
        usr.html("Empty field");
        return false;
    }
else
    {
    var username = usrn.val();
    usr.html('Cheking username...');
                alert(username);
    $.ajax({
            url: "userresponse.php",
            type: "POST",
            data: username,
            success: function (data) {  
            if(data.val() == "true")    
            {
                usr.html('Available username');
            }
            else if(data.val() == "false")
            {
                usr.html('Username already taken'); 

            }
          }})
      return data.val();
    }
});
        });
```

I know that AJAX is asynchronous and doesn't wait for the response from the server but I want to know how to fix it and make this call wait for the response.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please note that you have written a script that is vulnerable to [SQL Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) vulnerabilities because you have not sanitized any of the user-supplied variables in your SQL queries. Please use [PHP Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) to prevent these vulnerabilities. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have any experience with it myself, but isn't that what the `async` option is for?  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

```
$.ajax({
    url: "userresponse.php",
    /* etc */
    async: false,
    /* etc */
})
```

Answer (score 0):

you've already put a callback option "success:" in your $.ajax call
what's bothering you? it already does wait for the request to complete and gets response

Answer (score -1):

In your code, set async property to "true".

async property is "true" by default, but setting it to false will force the function to wait till it gets a response/time out.

Another way of working on this is to use success() and error() events.

Please refer to the following page for detailed documentations. Documentations for "settings" is what you want to look at:

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: actually you've got that backwards ... async is set to true by default (calls are asynchronous) and setting it to false tells it to make synchronous requests!

Comment: Hello guys thank you for your answers I confirm that Mr. BeatMasta was right there is no need for the async:false if you put a callback option "success:" in your $.ajax call. I had a problem whit my query witch made the ajax call fail.